# Nginx failed to start with ssl key error

Tags: nginx

Here is the error i am getting in nginx ssl:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/root/cert/l.key") failed (SSL:  error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

Searched everywhere but could not find its solution.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've stuck the key file into /root/cert.  Does the nginx process have the privs to descend into that directory?  I would be surprised if it did, as it typically will run as non-root.

Comment: yes, i have set the proper permissions. Even i tried with 777, but didnt worked.

Comment: What about the perms on /root?

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the file exist?
2. Does it contain a valid SSL key?
3. Does the key require a password?

---

This could be a special nginx problem.  Apache requires you to specify a separate `SSLCertificateChainFile` directive.  nginx requires you to concatenate any the intermediate chain certificates into the `.crt` file.  nginx can give this error if the first certificate in the `.crt` file is not the one that matches the key.  You have to concatenate the chain certs onto the end of your cert, not the other way around.

Comment: File does exists and its permissions are fine. Yes, the same file is working fine with Apache, but not with nginx. no, the key does not requires password

Comment: Tried by concatenating the chain certificate, still didnt worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect order?

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate

> If intermediate certificates should be specified in addition to a primary certificate, they should be specified in the same file in the following order: the primary certificate comes first, then the intermediate certificates.

Comment: Still didnt worked